# How to take string input from user's in Java and save it to a txt.file?

Tags: java, input, output

I am new in this so I hope some one can help me I want to know How to take string input from user's in Java and save it to a txt. file ? (and please explain how if you can)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: there are plenty of examples of this on stackoverflow, just go to the top right and enter the title of your problem in that search bar

Comment: Please make a minimal working example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Scanner` and `FileWriter`:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = s.nextLine();//read input from user
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\itama\\Desktop\\filename.txt");
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    fw.write(text);
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @SaadAL-awad then you should accept the answer. (V under answer score)